# Django views and templates

Tags: html, django

I have product_view.html file which contains

```
Product {{product.title}}
```

and I have view which have loaded information about model

```
template = loader.get_template(path)
context = {'title': product[0].title, 'description': product[0].description, 'image_url': product[0].image_url, 'quantity': product[0].quantity}
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

How I can render data to product_view.html, so it shows product.title? Now it only shows "Product" on the page. I am very new to django and it's very flustrating that I can't even do that :(

Comment: Theres a lot of things wrong here that would be too much to cover in one answer really.. instead it would be much more beneficial just to look at the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/)

Answer (score 2):

first make everything simple and clear!

```
template = 'YourTemplateFolder/product_view.html'
context = {"product":product[0]}
return render(request, template, context)
```

for the template, to print anything inside of it just put the variable name inside of two curly brackets

```
{{ product.title }} 
# product is the name you defined in context and by default it will take all of the variables attached to the original variable
```

and please in the future add more details to the question so people can help you instead of down-voting you.